# Adding linebreak in xml file before root node

Tags: java, xml, line-breaks, domparser

I am trying to add line break after my comments above the root node in XML document.

I need something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE-->
<projects>
</projects>
```

But What I was able to get is this(Line break inside the root but I need line break after the comment):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE--><projects>

</projects>
```

I need to add the line break just after my comment. Is there a way to do this?

My code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Comment;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class XMLNewLine {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Adding comment..");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        dbf.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder db;

        try {
            Document doc;
            StreamResult result;
            result = new StreamResult(new File("abc.xml"));
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("abc.xml")));

            Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
            Text lineBreak = doc.createTextNode("\n");

            element.appendChild(lineBreak);
            Comment comment = doc
                    .createComment("DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE");
            element.getParentNode().insertBefore(comment, element);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                    .newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.transform(source, result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *"I am trying to add line break after my comments above the root node in XML document."* - Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: (Don't answer, that was a rhetorical question. I understand it's purely for cosmetic reasons. I'm also not saying it would be impossible.)

Comment: @tomalak Thanks for your reply. This is to make sure the file looks good and readable before it is shipped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>You basically want a text node containing a line break after the comment node.</strike>

```
Element docElem = doc.getDocumentElement();

doc.insertBefore(doc.createComment("DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE"), docElem);
doc.insertBefore(doc.createTextNode("\\n"), docElem);
```

---

**EDIT**: It seems that appending even whitespace-only text nodes is not allowed at the root node of an `org.w3c.dom.Document`. This is 100% formally correct, but also unhelpful.

The way comments are rendered in the output of the `Transformer` is determined by the serializer it uses (there are different serializers for HTML, XML and plain text outputs). In the  built-in XML serializer the end of a comment is defined as `-->` - without a newline.

Since the internals of `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` are hard-wired, the serializers are not public API and the class is marked as `final`, overriding that behavior or setting a custom serializer is impossible.

In other words, you are out of luck adding your line break in a *clean* way.

You can, however, safely add it in a slightly unclean way:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

FileInputStream inputXml = new FileInputStream(new File("input.xml"));
Document doc = db.parse(inputXml);

// add the comment node    
doc.insertBefore(doc.createComment("THIS IS A COMMENT"), doc.getDocumentElement());

StringWriter outputXmlStringWriter = new StringWriter();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
// "xml" + "UTF-8" "include XML declaration" is the default anyway, but let's be explicit
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(outputXmlStringWriter));

// now insert our newline into the string & write an UTF-8 file
String outputXmlString = outputXmlStringWriter.toString()
    .replaceFirst("<!--", "\n<!--").replaceFirst("-->", "-->\n");

FileOutputStream outputXml = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.xml"));            
outputXml.write(outputXmlString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Doing search-and-replace operations on XML strings is highly discouraged in general, but in this case there is little that can go wrong.

Comment: I am getting below error 
**_org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. _**

when is use the code below:
`doc.insertBefore(doc.createTextNode("\\n"), docElem);`

Comment: @Murali See modified answer.

Answer (score 8):

Revisiting this after some time because I had the same issue. I found another solution that does not need to buffer the output in a String:

1. Write only the XML-declaration by passing an empty document. This will also append a linebreak.
2. Write the document content without XML-declaration

Code:

```
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(writer);
// output XML declaration with an empty document
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(), streamResult);
// output the document without XML declaration
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), streamResult);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by not adding the comment node to your document, but instead partially transforming your document. First transform your own XML processing instruction and comment separately, and then the rest of document:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("abc.xml")));

Result output = new StreamResult(new File("abc.xml"));
Source input = new DOMSource(doc);


// xml processing instruction and comment node
ProcessingInstruction xmlpi = doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"");
Comment comment = doc.createComment("DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE");

// first transform the processing instruction and comment
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(xmlpi), output);
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(comment), output);
// then the document
transformer.transform(input, output);
```

Comment: It works with `FileOutputStream` instead of `File` in `Result output = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("abc.xml"));`

Answer (score 2):

There is a [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7150637) concerning this. It was not fixed (as you would expect) because that would likely cause many problems to users' existing applications.

Adding the following output property fixes this:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("http://www.oracle.com/xml/is-standalone", "yes");
```

Comment: I checked your code. It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
I solved it by putting the comment inside the root element.
Not exactly the same, but I think acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I just take writer and write to it declaration and the header comment. After that I disable declaration in transformer this way

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

All code:

```
public static String xmlToTree(String xml, String headerComment) {
        try (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml)) {
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            result.getWriter().write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n");
            result.getWriter().write(headerComment + "\n");
            
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            
            StreamSource source = new StreamSource(reader);
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            String xmlTree = result.getWriter().toString();
            return xmlTree;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```